# composite and foreign keys as primary key doctrine 2 + zend framework 2

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-form, zend-framework2

I have been wondering why my mappings and the controller actions are not working. For this I need to refer to my previous post, where I have described my entities and database schema, which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693023/save-entities-in-database-using-one-to-many-relationship-using-doctrine-2-and-ze). I need to start a new post since there were no further updates and I thought this the only way to get attention of the Doctrine + Zend Pros.

As described in my previous post, I have a Zend Form, the user can enter teamId and teamName, further he has the choice to select multiple players from the drop down list on the form and can allocate players to the team. So basically that is my goal to achieve with Doctrine and Zend. For that I wrote my entities described in the previous post and right now I want to add the code from my controller to persist the entities.

Controller:

```
 public function addAction()
    {
        $form = new TeamForm($this->getEntityManager());

        $form->get('submit')->setAttribute('value', 'Add');

        $request = $this->getRequest();

        if ($request->isPost())
        {
            $team = new Team();
            $player = new Player();
            $teamPlayers = new TeamPlayer();

            $form->setInputFilter($typeset->getInputFilter());

            $form->setData($request->getPost());

            if ($form->isValid())
            {
                $team->populate($form->getData());

                $teamPlayers->setPlayer($player);
                $teamPlayers->setTeam($team);

                $this->getEntityManager()->persist($teamPlayers);

                $this->getEntityManager()->flush();

               //Reroute to the index page once the data is successfully added
            }
        }
        //return form array
        return array(
            'form' => $form
            );
    }
```

So that is basically what Im doing in my controller to save the entities into two tables (team Table and teamPlayer Table), as already the player Table is populated with data. So I want to add players to the team and assign that values in these two tables.

Right now I can see my form and when I enter the data and press submit nothing is happening, i can see the form with no action. When the data is successfully saved into the database then I reroute it to the index page which is not happening.

Any help would be appreciated, to point out the error Im making either in mapping section or in the controller side.

The official documentation especially from Doctrine 2 is too global and is particulary not that clear for my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

let's try to solve it by updating this answer by steps :

step 1 : 
your words implied to me that , you might have some issues in from validation , so lets check if you are passing this `$form->isValid()`

```
 if ($form->isValid())
            {
                $team->populate($form->getData());
                $teamPlayers->setPlayer($player);
                $teamPlayers->setTeam($team);
                $this->getEntityManager()->persist($teamPlayers);
                $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
               //Reroute to the index page once the data is successfully added
            }else{
         var_dump($form->getMessages());

}
```

I can also suggest you to use doctrine commandline : `doctrine orm:validate-schema` , this command will help you to check if your entity mapping is ok plus your database mapping is also okay , i see it as handy to to debug your doctrine2 entity

ps : I havn't read your entities in depth yet

Comment: thanks for your reply, but this does not help in finding the exact solution I  have been looking for